# HybridAuth - 'Update user status failed! Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, hybridauth

I have integrated latest version of HybridAuth in my website, I have created Facebook app as well, but when I use the function

```
$facebook->setUserStatus("Test");
```

it return for me error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Update user status failed! Facebook returned an error: OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' in /home2/codinghe/public_html/clients/2014/yomi/wp-content/themes/sparkling/inc/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php:204
```

I think by default, Facebook config allow already publish and write stream in HybridAuth. The issue can be in my facebook app ? here is how it looks:

http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/743/9943073222.jpg

Do you have any idea please? You can test the integration here:

http://clients.codinghero.net/2014/yomi/?page_id=14

Thank you for your help

Comment: You need to ask the user for permission to post stuff